# the given path format is not supported; streamwriter

Tags: c#

Below are the Stacktrace;

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=The given path's format is not supported.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at EntryLog.Handlers.StreamEntryLogs.StreamWritter(String log, String foldername) in C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\EntryLog\EntryLog\Handlers\StreamEntryLogs.cs:line 31
   at EntryLog.EntryLog.LogWarning(String Warning) in C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\EntryLog\EntryLog\EntryLog.cs:line 55
   at EntryLogConsoleTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\EntryLogConsoleTest\EntryLogConsoleTest\Program.cs:line 21

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(string)
    System.IO.FileStream.Init(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, int, bool, System.IO.FileShare, int, System.IO.FileOptions, Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, string, bool, bool, bool)
    System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)
    EntryLog.Handlers.StreamEntryLogs.StreamWritter(string, string) in StreamEntryLogs.cs
    EntryLog.EntryLog.LogWarning(string) in EntryLog.cs
    EntryLogConsoleTest.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

The exception is coming about from the following lines;

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(EntryLog.LogPath.AbsolutePath, currentTimeFilename + " - " + $"{foldername}.log");


var fileStreamer = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStreamer);
```

The LogPath is obtained by this method;

```
LogPath = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
```

I have tried all manner of debugging but it always throws the above exception at StreamWriter. Kindly assist me in resolving this. I'm using 4.5.2 .net Framework

**FILE PATH**

The file path in question is this;
`C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\EntryLogConsoleTest\EntryLogConsoleTest\bin\Debug`

**CURRENT TIME AND FOLDER NAME**

`string currentTimeFilename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`

`string foldername = "Log"`

Comment: Could you show what has `filepath`? And then just see whether this address exists in your system

Comment: Added the file path

Comment: @MongZhu added the two variables

Comment: `string foldername = "Log"` is this the value from the debugger? I can only reproduce your exception if I use a path like `@"C:\foo\folderName"` as value for the variable `foldername`

Comment: Debug the code and give us the result of the `filePath` variable before it is sent to the FileStream.

Comment: "Debug the code and give us the result of the filePath variable before it is sent to the FileStream. –" preferably with a screenshot

Comment: It's string since it's a variable set on a method call; that's why I concatenate the path with the + sign in `path.Combine`

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, the question has literally everything that it needs, John is responsive and we solved that thing under 30 Minutes. ...

Comment: @MongZhu Except that he has not given us the value if the variable that actually generates the error.

Comment: @Magnus so the person who downvoted, just passed by, clicked and did not obrseve that the post was vividly changed. Now would be actually the time to retract that vote :) well yes that is how it works on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is the `:` in your filename

```
string currentTimeFilename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); 
                                                                 ^
```

Change it to `-` or `_` or even a `.` for example and the error disappears

```
string currentTimeFilename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm");
```

Comment: Probably the space character is a problem also since URI will translate that to `%`

Comment: @Magnus no, I tested it, it works even if you replace `:` by a `%`, but it gives a weird result though

Answer (score 3):

Using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) you can find that the code of the method `EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks` (which raises the [NotSupportedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.8)) is:

```
internal static void EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(string fullPath)
{
    if (AppContextSwitches.UseLegacyPathHandling || !PathInternal.IsDevice(fullPath))
    {
        if (PathInternal.HasWildCardCharacters(fullPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_InvalidPathChars"));
        }
        if (PathInternal.HasInvalidVolumeSeparator(fullPath))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_PathFormatNotSupported"));
        }
    }
}
```

So your path contains invalid chars.

**EDIT**

If in your settings hours - minutes separator is a colon (see your datetime formatted string), please consider that ':' cannot be used in a path, but after driver letter.